# ng-repeat with JSON object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

It must be the heat...

I have a json object that I want to run through a ng-repeat, should be simple, but alas! it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<a data-ng-repeat="x in template.menuObj" href="{{ x.link }}">{{ x.name }}</a>
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"home",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"Home",
        "order":1,
        "objectId":"aDcb0HUXwB",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:29:05.948Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:29:11.915Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-interesting-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Interesting Stuff",
        "order":2,
        "objectId":"znXfUF0kdJ",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:11.332Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:39.738Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-fun-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Fun Stuff",
        "order":3,
        "objectId":"WiPmXdhaOu",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:44.667Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:06.058Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-nerdy-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Nerdy Stuff",
        "order":4,
        "objectId":"Z0aSsnpV0B",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:09.859Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:33.564Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"page/about-me",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"About Me",
        "order":5,
        "objectId":"Gm35DOju7t",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:37.759Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:55.387Z"
    }
]
```

When I run this, I get 5 empty `<a>`'s, something like:

```
<a data-ng-repeat="x in template.menuObj" href="" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></a>
```

So I guess angular sees the 5 arrays, but somehow the keys are not caught?

EDIT: This is how the json object is created (via parse.com):

```
var Menu = Parse.Object.extend('Menu');
var query = new Parse.Query(Menu);
query.ascending('order');
query.equalTo('menu', 'main');
query.find().then(function(results){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    $scope.template.menuObj = results;
}, function(error){
    // error-handling
    console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

EDIT EDIT: Controller etc.

```
blogApp.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, templateService) {
    $scope.template = templateService;

    var Menu = Parse.Object.extend('Menu');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Menu);
    query.ascending('order');
    query.equalTo('menu', 'main');
    query.find().then(function(results){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        $scope.template.menuObj = results;
    }, function(error){
        // error-handling
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

templateService is a factory that binds a parent controller. It's important to note that before I started messing with parse.com for this project, the ng-repeat worked just fine when I retrieved ($http) a json object via PHP/MySQL.

EDIT EDIT EDIT: uploaded a screendump of `console.log(results);`
[image]

Comment: I assume the JSON is `template.menuObj`, correct?

Comment: @mypal125 Yup, it is, but I send it not as JSON.stringify()

Comment: seems to work fine, i can't reproduce the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/fq0OjSbXFRjfiYgsSDeA?p=preview

Comment: @j.wittwer hang on, you did something in that plnkr that I didn't do. Lemme just test it, and then if you make it an answer I will accept :)

Comment: @j.wittwer I thought it might be your `$scope.template = { menuObj: results }` solution, but nope... Doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: Where do you assign the json to $scope.template? could you please post the controller?

Comment: Could you log `results` please?

Comment: @JonthanSolorzano Controller added to OP. Log results? Not sure what you mean

Comment: `console.log(results);` and add it as an update to the question @BrianEmilius, because that's what you're assigning to `$scope.template.menuObj`, maybe you should do `$scope.template.menuObj = JSON.stringify(results);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85223/discussion-between-jonthan-solorzano-and-brian-emilius).

Comment: Yes, but with `JSON.stringify(results);` I get a DUPES error (ng-repeat cannot handle duplicate keys). The result-log is a tree-style array, cannot copy/paste it. However, the array has 5 objects, each with `attribute: {link:"linkname",name:"name"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that `results` is the array object, and you are assigning it to `$scope.template.menuObj` but the json array doesn't have a name. You could either give it a name:

```
"menuObj": [
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"home",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"Home",
        "order":1,
        "objectId":"aDcb0HUXwB",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:29:05.948Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:29:11.915Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-interesting-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Interesting Stuff",
        "order":2,
        "objectId":"znXfUF0kdJ",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:11.332Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:39.738Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-fun-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Fun Stuff",
        "order":3,
        "objectId":"WiPmXdhaOu",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:33:44.667Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:06.058Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"category/the-nerdy-stuff",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"The Nerdy Stuff",
        "order":4,
        "objectId":"Z0aSsnpV0B",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:09.859Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:33.564Z"
    },
    {
        "ACL":{
            "*":{
                "read":true
            }
        },
        "link":"page/about-me",
        "menu":"main",
        "name":"About Me",
        "order":5,
        "objectId":"Gm35DOju7t",
        "createdAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:37.759Z",
        "updatedAt":"2015-08-05T15:34:55.387Z"
    }
];
```

Or leave it like you have it, but the controller must be like this:

```
blogApp.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, templateService) {
    $scope.template = templateService;

    var Menu = Parse.Object.extend('Menu');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Menu);
    query.ascending('order');
    query.equalTo('menu', 'main');
    query.find().then(function(results){
        $scope.template = JSON.stringify(results);
    }, function(error){
        // error-handling
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

And the view like this:

```
<body ng-app="blogApp"><!-- angular.module('blogApp', []); -->
<div ng-controller="templateCtrl" >
    <nav ng-repeat="a in template">
      <a href="{{ a.link }}">{{ a.name }}</a>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

But in the case you want to work with it as you have it you should do it this way:

```
<body ng-app="blogApp"><!-- angular.module('blogApp', []); -->
<div ng-controller="templateCtrl" >
    <nav ng-repeat="a in template.menuObj">
      <a href="{{ a.get('link') }}">{{ a.get('name') }}</a>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonthan, the bottom suggestion works like a charm. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Nah, you gave a lot of your time on this, and I appreciate it, also, your answer is quite detailed.